# jQuery scrollTop jumping on FF and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have a jQuery scrollTop function that is activated on a button click, i also have a scrollView function that is activated on scroll.

The intention is that the landing image is either clicked or the user scrolls down, the landing image is hidden by the jQuery and the navigation menu shows.

This is working well in Chrome, but in FF and Safari, the page jumps further down the page and you have to scroll back up to see the top of the page.

Also, using the Divi WP theme.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Code below is what i have used, apologies new to Jquery so have put things together from different places, i'm sure this can be made simpler!

```js
//click-scroll-hide
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cf_news_link").click(function() {
      $("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#news").offset().top
      }, 1000, function() {
        $("#cf_my-header").hide();
        $("#main-header").slideDown("slow");
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
})(jQuery);

//scroll-hide
jQuery(function($) {
  $.fn.scrollView = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
      });
    });
  }
  var $header = $('#cf_my-header');
  var $win = $(window);
  var winH = $win.height();
  $win.on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > winH) {
      $header.addClass("hide");
      $('#news').scrollTop();
      $('#main-header').slideDown("slow");
    }
  }).on("resize", function() {
    winH = $(this).height();
  });
});
```

Comment: Add your relevant html/css also.

Comment: Using Divi WP Theme, not sure how to show html/ css here?